# Convert ireg to XML

Tags: python, xml

I'm working on a Python script to convert an ireg file to XML. I've found a lot of things about XML in Python, but nothing about ireg.

I suppose the way to do this is to take the ireg file as input and make a "dictionary" from ireg syntax to XML, but I don't have any idea where to start and if that's gonna work.

If you could give me any sort of tips I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is ireg? Got a link?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could work but it depends on what the format of ireg is. Some broad steps I think you will need to do are:

1. Write some python to read in the file line by line [(tutorial)](https://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/python/reading-files/)
2. Work out the how to split/parse the lines into your dictionary. I don't know what the format of ireg is, that is something you will have to work out. If it were a simple comma-separate format with no headers you could for example do something like:

   ```
   dict = {}
   lines = f.readlines()
   for line in lines:
       fields = line.split(',')
       dict[fields[0]] = fields[1]
   ```
3. Write out your dictionary in XML format [(tutorial)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-serialize-Python-dictionary-to-XML)